# Behat 3 and Mink Extension on Ubuntu error in FeatureContext

Tags: behat, mink

Depending on if my `FeatureContext` class extends `RawMinkContext` or `MinkContext` I'm having issues running Behat tests.

Here's my `FeatureContext.php`

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface;
use Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext;
use Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;

use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterStepScope;
use Goutte\Client;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext {

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     * Every scenario gets its own context object.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param array $parameters context parameters (set them up through behat.yml)
     * @return null
     */

    public function __construct() {

    }/* __construct() */

}
?>
```

and my `behat.yml`

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            path: %paths.base%/features
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://somesite.com'
            goutte: ~
            javascript_session: selenium2
            files_path: 'vendor'
            selenium2: ~
            sessions:
                default:
                    goutte: ~
                goutte:
                    goutte: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2: ~
                symfony2:
                    symfony2: ~
    formatters:
        html:
            output_path: %paths.base%/reports
```

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSession() on a non-object in /home/behat/composer/vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/RawMinkContext.php on line 101`

If I `extend` `RawMinkContext` instead of `MinkContext` then the tests run, but it adds (blank) versions of the default steps that are defined in MinkContext (i.e. If I am on [url] or When I go to [url] etc. ).

If I run `behat -c ./config/behat.yml` (or, just `./behat.yml` - I have an identical behat.yml file in both locations as I wasn't sure it was being used properly) I get the same results as above. I'm almost certainly doing something dumb...

My `composer.json` for reference:

```
{
"name": "behat mink skeleton",
"require": {
  "behat/behat":  "*",
  "behat/mink-extension": "*",
  "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "*",
  "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
  "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
  "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "*",
  "teaandcode/behat-guzzle-extension": "*",
  "sauce/sausage": ">=0.5",
  "sauce/connect": ">=3.0",
  "emuse/behat-html-formatter": "dev-master"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/",
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "ac1dd3678488663ccc1ba02a5d1d474e1a78bb93"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have many examples [heres](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat) for how to use bahat2, behat3, relevant composer files, behat.yml files, FeatureContext files so on. Getting the session differs depending on what class you're extending. you can search `getSession` in that blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend MinkContext in FeatureContext then remove MinkContext from behat.yml.
behat.yml file should contain only the local context under contexts section, in your case you don't need MinkContext or RawAwareContext, only FeatureContext.